# Direct3D9 Can't get vertical fov camera working

Tags: c++, view, camera, directx, direct3d

I'm trying getting started with Direct 3D. But i can't get the fov camera working. At least not the vertical movement. I figured out why but i still can't fix it.

I'm using C++ (140) and D3DX9

Code:

```
D3DXMATRIX viewMat;

static D3DXMATRIX viewRotXMat;
static D3DXMATRIX viewRotYMat;
static D3DXMATRIX viewRotZMat;

static float rotY = 0.0f;
static float rotXZ = 0.0f;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) { rotY += 0.1f; }
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) { rotY -= 0.1f; }

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) { rotXZ += 0.1f; }
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) { rotXZ -= 0.1f; }

//POINT pMO = getMouseOffset();
//rotY += pMO.x / 10;
//rotXZ += pMO.y / 10;

D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&viewMat,
    &D3DXVECTOR3(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f), //pos
    &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f),  //look-at
    &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); //weird values


D3DXMatrixRotationY(&viewRotYMat, rotY);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&viewRotXMat, cos(rotY) * rotXZ);
D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&viewRotZMat, (sin(rotY) * rotXZ) * -1);

d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &(viewMat * viewRotXMat * viewRotYMat * viewRotZMat));


D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projMat,
                           D3DXToRadian(90),
                           (FLOAT)SIZEX / (FLOAT)SIZEY,
                           1.0f,
                           1000.0f);
d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &projMat);
```

This is the important part of my RenderFrame function.
The reason why it won't work is because of 
rotY and rotXZ. For some reason when i turn the camera about 45° ingame the rotY variable only changes to 3-4. So why the heck is't the D3DXMatrixRotationY function taking an angle as an parameter but some float? The parameter is even named angle...  I'm on this problem for about 3 days now. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Is your angle `rotY` in radians or degrees? It should be passed to `D3DXMatrixRotationY` (and `cos`/`sin` for that matter) as radians. Also taking the address of a temporary rvalue in `&(viewMat * viewRotXMat * viewRotYMat * viewRotZMat)` is not standard-conform, but your compiler may support it.

Comment: This is the way the directx tutorial was showing to do it.http://www.directxtutorial.com/

Comment: rotY is apparently in radians. but i defined a new float which is rotY in degrees for sin cos. but it still does the same fails as beforehand. it flips arround 45*, 135* etc.

Comment: `sin` and `cos` most definetly would expect radians too, but that is hardly the source of flipping

Comment: You misunderstood me, you should pass `rotY` in radians, not degree, to all functions. Very seldom angles are represented in degrees in programming internals. It would also be helpful if you refered to the exact tutorial page you are working with, so one can understand what your calculations are supposed to achieve.

Comment: i am passing rotY etc as radians. i convert them with this formula: radian = degree * (PI / 180);

I'm not working with a tutorial because i just want to look up down left right. and all of the tutorials are very complicated with a lot of stuff that i don't even need. In most of them the camera rotation isn't well explained so i can't just take this part.

My calculations for the view doenst work with sin(degree) neither with sin(radiant).

Comment: Which i dont unterstand. I calculated everything exactly like my program does with a calculator and rotated the camera in Blender (as a visualisation) exactly like my program would and it works perfect. But in directx int doesnt. :(

Comment: Since you have Visual C++ 2015 (you stated you are using ``v140``), why are you using the 12+ year old Direct3D 9 API that requires the deprecated [D3DX9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) library? You should focus on learning DIrect3D 11 instead ideally without using the legacy DirectX SDK at all. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 2):

Your setup for rotation matrix looks a bit weird:

```
D3DXMatrixRotationY(&viewRotYMat, rotY);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&viewRotXMat, cos(rotY) * rotXZ);
D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&viewRotZMat, (sin(rotY) * rotXZ) * -1);
```

What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Usually you would just do a couple of axis rotations and then combine them, and your code looks like exactly that, but with messed order of matrix combination, which is then compensated with some explicit trigonometry. There's a good chance you could do the same with just

```
D3DXMatrixRotationY(&viewRotYMat, rotY);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&viewRotXMat, rotXZ);
```

Otherwise you could use `D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll` to at least combine the 3 angles in one line.

As for the `rotY` value, remember that it is expected to be measured in radians, so 3-4 corresponds to 180°. Observing 45° instead could be explained by `rotXZ` contribution.

Comment: Thank you. But somehow the camera still does this flips arround 0* 90* usw.

Changes:


float deg = rotY * (180 / PI);


 D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&viewRotXMat, rotY, sin(deg) * rotXZ, (cos(deg) * rotXZ) * -1);


i commented the rotationxyz setup out.

Comment: As I said, you have this weird 3-angle combination, this could lead to gimbal lock and all kind of flipping, for POV camera please try using just 2 angles with no trigonometry calls at all

Comment: Such a function would be perfect but i couldn't find one. Do you know the name by any chance?

Comment: Yep, I suggested it in the answer - the `D3DXMatrixRotationY(&viewRotYMat, rotY);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&viewRotXMat, rotXZ);` part; the resulting matrix would be `viewRotMat = viewRotYMat*viewRotXMat;`

Comment: Euler angles for camera's are problematic due to [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) which is why you either need to constrain the rotation values to avoid the 90-degree cases or use a quaternion for the rotation instead.